# OpenGL: Screen goes white when I pass GL_NONE to both glDrawBuffer and glReadBuffer

Tags: opengl, fbo, depth-buffer

I want to do a depth only pass in my renderer.  I have created a FBO for this pass, and I attach only a depth buffer to it.  I also pass GL_NONE to both glDrawBuffer and glReadBuffer, as per this thread:

[Rendering multiple depth information with FBOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669830/rendering-multiple-depth-information-with-fbos)

However, after this frame draws, the screen goes completely white.  If I disable that pass, then I see the expected output (resulting from the other passes).

Any ideas on why this is happening?  At first, I was reusing an existing FBO (that handles offscreen rendering) for the depth only pass.  I then created another FBO for just this scenario.  Both approaches still result in a white screen.

Does this article offer a possible source of the problem?

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/149004-glDrawBuffer(-GL_NONE-)-expected-behaviour

Using apitrace (https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace), I can now show the OpenGL code that I believe is responsible for the white screen:

[Offending OpenGL code http://imageshack.us/a/img855/7660/jmkq.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img855/7660/jmkq.png)

In this simple example, I am attaching only the depth attachment to FBO 2.  I then pass 0 to both glFramebufferTexture2D() and glFramebufferRenderbuffer() to detach any previous attachments at GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, and pass GL_NONE to both glDrawBuffer() and glReadBuffer().  I then immediately bind the default FBO (0), and restore the viewport back to 1280x720.  I also pass GL_BACK to both glDrawBuffer() and glReadBuffer().

After this, both the working and non-working versions of my code proceed to bind another FBO for offscreen rendering.  I then attach to both GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT using glFramebufferTexture2D() and glFramebufferRenderbuffer(), respectively.  For glDrawBuffer() and glReadBuffer(), I provide GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0.

Does this make things clearer?  I'm not quite sure how the above code snippet is causing my screen to go white.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Or rather, *some* information. A general description isn't enough to find code bugs.

Comment: Just updated the question.  Is this better?